# Join row with MAX row in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql

How do I join a row from one table to a row with the MAX value for a given column on another table?

For example, I have a `auctions` table and an `auction_bids` table. I want to join the auctions table with the highest bid for that auction (i.e. highest value for column `bid_amount` AND where `auction_id` = `x`) in the `auction_bids` table.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the answers submitted so far are all incorrect - they fetch the highest bid, but not the entire corresponding row from `auction_bids` - am I right?

Comment: Unfortunately, mysql does not support windowing functions, which were made for exactly this type of question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's annoyingly complicated. You'd be better off with a "winner" flag in each winning auction_bid.

```
SELECT * FROM auctions a
INNER JOIN 
(
    /* now get just the winning rows */
    SELECT * FROM auction_bids x
    INNER JOIN
    (
        /* how to tell the winners */
        SELECT auction_id, MAX(bid_amount) as winner
        FROM auction_bids
        GROUP BY auction_id
    ) y
    ON x.auction_id = y.auction_id
    AND x.bid_amount = y.winner
) b
ON a.auction_id = b.auction_id
```

Note that auctions with zero bids will not be listed at all, and auctions with ties (can that happen?) will appear once for each tied bid.

Comment: in my case all i needed to do was add a join to my current query, didnt need extra sub queries, but this helped anyways

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.*, bid_amount
  FROM auction a INNER JOIN 
    (
     SELECT auction_id, MAX(bid_amount)  AS bid_amount
       FROM auction_bids
         WHERE acution_id = x
         GROUP BY auction_id
    ) b
    ON a.auction_id = b.auction_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.id, MAX(ab.bid_amount)
FROM auctions AS a
INNER JOIN action_bids AS ab 
   ON a.id = ab.auction_id
GROUP BY a.id;
```

Add more columns to your `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` clauses as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 Select A.ID,max(AB.bit_amount) 
 From  auctions A Inner Join Auction_bids AB on A.ID = AB.auction_ID
 Where A.ID = x
 Group By A.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to use a sub query to do this in the actual join.

```
Select bid as highest_bid
  from auctions
    left outer join auctions_bids on action_bids.ref_no = auctions.ref_no
     and (select max(bid) from auctions_bids as ab 
           where auctions_bid.ref_no = a2.ref_no)
```