# Mysql JOIN with extra priority column

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two days trying to do this query with no luck. 
I have two tables 'DEMAND' and 'DEMAND_STATE' (one to many relation). The table DEMAND_STATE have millions entries.

```
CREATE TABLE DEMAND
(
   ID          INT            NOT NULL,
   DESTINY_ID  INT            NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE DEMAND_STATE
(
   ID         INT      NOT NULL,
   PRIORITY   INT      NOT NULL,
   QUANTITY   DOUBLE   NOT NULL,
   CASE_ID    INT      NOT NULL,
   DEMAND_ID  INT      NOT NULL,
   PHASE_ID   INT      NOT NULL
)
```

The QUANTITY of the DEMAND_STATE is given according to a CASE_ID and PHASE_ID. We have 'N' PHASES in 'M' CASES. Always the same number of Phases in all Cases. We always have a initial Base Quantity called 'BASE CASE' in the Case with CASE_ID = 1.

For example to obtain quantity for Case (id=2) and Case Base (id=1)

```
select D.*, S.PRIORITY, S.QUANTITY, S.CASE_ID, S.DEMAND_ID, S.PHASE_ID
FROM DEMAND D 
join DEMAND_STATE S on (D.ID = S.DEMAND_ID)
WHERE (S.CASE_ID = 2 OR S.CASE_ID = 1)
```

(paste only for id=8)

```
ID  PRIORITY    QUANTITY    CASE_ID DEMAND_ID   PHASE_ID
8   0   85  1   8   1
8   0   83  1   8   2
8   0   88  1   8   3
8   0   89  1   8   4

8   10  85  2   8   1
8   10  84  2   8   2
8   10  86  2   8   3
8   10  89  2   8   4
```

We need to obtain for all Demand in 'DEMAND' only the Quantity for Each Phase with MAX priority. The idea is no duplicate DEMAND_STATE data for each new Case creation. Only create new state rows when Demand-Case-Phase is different to Case Base. This is a new project and we accept changes in model for better performance.

I also tried with the MAX calculation. This query over DEMAND_STATE works fine but only obtain data for a concrete DEMAND_ID. Further i think this solution can be so expensive.

```
SELECT P.ID, P.QUANTITY, P.CASE_ID, P.DEMAND_ID, P.PHASE_ID
FROM DEMAND_STATE P
    JOIN (
        SELECT PHASE_ID, MAX(PRIORITY) max_priority, S.DEMAND_ID
        from DEMAND_STATE S
        WHERE S.DEMAND_ID = 1
    AND (S.CASE_ID=1 OR S.CASE_ID=2)
        GROUP BY S.PHASE_ID
    ) SUB 
ON (SUB.PHASE_ID = P.PHASE_ID AND SUB.max_priority = P.PRIORITY)
WHERE P.DEMAND_ID = 1
GROUP BY P.PHASE_ID
```

The result:

```
ID  QUANTITY    CASE_ID DEMAND_ID   PHASE_ID
1   86  1   1   1
2   85  1   1   2
3   81  1   1   3
8   500 2   1   4
```

This is the result expected:

```
ID  ID  PRIORITY    QUANTITY    CASE_ID PHASE_ID
8   1   0   86  1   1       (data from Case Base id=1 priority 0)
8   2   10  85  1   2       (data from Case Baseid=1 priority 0)
8   3   10  81  1   3       (data from Case Base id=1 priority 0)
8   64  10  500 2   4       (data from Case id=2 priority 10)
```

thank for help :)

Edit:

**Result of Simon proposal:**

```
ID  QUANTITY    CASE_ID DEMAND_ID   PHASE_ID
1   86  1   1   1
2   85  1   1   2
3   81  1   1   3
4   84  1   1   4    (this row shouldnt exist)
8   500 2   1   4    (this is the correct row)
```

Also would have to join it with DEMAND

**@didierc response:**

```
ID  ID  MAX(S.PRIORITY) QUANTITY    CASE_ID PHASE_ID
1   8   10  500 2   4
2   13  10  81  2   1
2   14  10  83  2   2
2   15  10  84  2   3
3   21  10  81  2   1
4   31  10  86  2   3
4   32  10  80  2   4
4   29  10  85  2   1
4   30  10  81  2   2
```

we need for each DEMAND four rows with the quantity Value. In Case Base we have four quantity and in Case 2 we only change the quantity for phase 4. We need always four rows for each demand.

Database DEMAND_STATE data:

```
ID  PRIORITY    QUANTITY    CASE_ID DEMAND_ID   PHASE_ID
1   0   86  1   1   1
2   0   85  1   1   2
3   0   81  1   1   3
4   0   84  1   1   4

8   10  500 2   1   4
```

Comment: I think you're trying to get the 'maximum row', which is difficult. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7503220/join-row-with-max-row-in-another-table

Comment: “We have 'N' PHASES in 'N' CASES", these 2 numbers are equals, correct?

Comment: “We need to obtain for all Demand in 'DEMAND' only the Quantity for Each Phase with MAX priority“. I read this as : `select max(priority) group by phase_id`, but you might want to group by `phase_id, demand_id`?

Comment: @didierc is not equals. We can have two Cases with three Phases. The number of phases is always the same. Exist other entity as top level called Model. Model -> Cases -> Phases. One model has always the same number of phases in all Cases.

Comment: What do you mean by "Only create new state rows when Demand-Case-Phase is different to Case Base"? In the result set?

Comment: It is a problem of demand previsions. For example all the towns of a region will demand in summer (phase 1) 10 units and in winter (phase 2) 5 units. This would be our initial Case base. Suppose we want to test what would happen if in winter only request 1 unit. The problem would be  for hundreds of towns  and we want to make small changes to the Base Case. We will Create Case 1, 2 ... based on the Base Case and make minor changes in 'Quantity'. When we show all demand rows by Case we must show the quantity for each phase in the selected Case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We need to obtain for all Demand in 'DEMAND' only the Quantity for Each Phase with MAX priority

I translate the above, according to your sample result set, as:

```
SELECT 
  D.ID, S.ID, MAX(S.PRIORITY), S.QUANTITY, S.CASE_ID, S.PHASE_ID
FROM DEMAND D
LEFT JOIN DEMAND_STATE S
ON D.ID = S.DEMAND_ID
GROUP BY S.PHASE_ID, S.DEMAND_ID
```

#### Update:

To get the maximum priority for each pair(demand_id,phase_id)n we use the following query:

```
SELECT
  DEMAND_ID, PHASE_ID, MAX(PRIORITY) AS PRIORITY
FROM DEMAND_STATE
GROUP BY DEMAND_ID, PHASE_ID
```

Next, to retrieve the set of phases for a given demand, just make an inner join on demand state:

```
SELECT S.* FROM DEMAND_STATE S
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    DEMAND_ID, PHASE_ID, MAX(PRIORITY) AS PRIORITY
  FROM DEMAND_STATE
  GROUP BY DEMAND_ID, PHASE_ID
) S2
USING (DEMAND_ID,PHASE_ID, PRIORITY)
WHERE DEMAND_ID = 1
```

If you want to limit the possible cases, include a where clause in the query `S2`:

```
SELECT S.* FROM DEMAND_STATE S
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    DEMAND_ID, PHASE_ID, MAX(PRIORITY) AS PRIORITY
  FROM DEMAND_STATE
  WHERE CASE_ID IN (1,2)
  GROUP BY DEMAND_ID, PHASE_ID
) S2
USING (DEMAND_ID,PHASE_ID, PRIORITY)
WHERE DEMAND_ID = 1
```

However, your comments and update indicates that `MAX(PRIORITY)`  does not seem very relevant after all.  My understanding is that you have a base case, which may be overriden by another case in a given scenario (that scenario is the pair base case + some other case). Clarify that point in your question body if this is incorrect.  If that is the case, you may change the above query by replacing `PRIORITY` by `CASE_ID`:

```
SELECT S.* FROM DEMAND_STATE S
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    DEMAND_ID, PHASE_ID, MAX(CASE_ID) AS CASE_ID
  FROM DEMAND_STATE
  WHERE CASE_ID IN (1,2)
  GROUP BY DEMAND_ID, PHASE_ID
) S2
USING (DEMAND_ID,PHASE_ID, CASE_ID)
WHERE DEMAND_ID = 1
```

The only reason I see from having a priority is if you wish to combine more than 2 cases, and use priority to select which case will prevail depending on the phase.

---

You may of course prepend an inner join on `DEMAND` to include the related demand data.

Comment: We need for each DEMAND four rows with the quantity Value. In Case Base we have four quantity and in Case 2 we only change the quantity for phase 4. We need always four rows for each demand. I posted results in top. thanks

Comment: Yep! your solution work fine :) You are right with priority field.  What do you think about this query? could it be so expensive with thousand data? Maximum 2M data in STATE. Thank you didierc

Comment: If you add an index on `demand_id, phase_id, case_id` together, the server will be able to avoid a filesort, which should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use of subqueries should be able to do as you wish, if I understand your question correctly. Something along the lines of the following:

```
SELECT
    P.ID, 
    P.QUANTITY, 
    P.CASE_ID, 
    P.DEMAND_ID, 
    P.PHASE_ID
FROM DEMAND_STATE P

INNER JOIN (
    -- Next level up groups it down and so gets the rows first returned for each PHASE_ID, which is the highest priority due to the subquery
    SELECT
        D.PHASE_ID,
        D.PRIORITY,
        D.DEMAND_ID
    FROM (
        -- Top level query to get all rows and order them in desc priority order
        SELECT 
            S.PHASE_ID, 
            S.PRIORITY, 
            S.DEMAND_ID
        FROM DEMAND_STATE S
        WHERE S.DEMAND_ID IN (1) -- Update this to be whichever DEMAND_IDs you are interested in
        AND S.CASE_ID IN (1,2)
        ORDER BY 
            S.PHASE_ID ASC,
            S.DEMAND_ID ASC,
            S.PRIORITY DESC
    ) D
    GROUP BY 
        D.PHASE_ID,
        S.DEMAND_ID
) SUB
ON SUB.PHASE_ID = P.PHASE_ID
AND SUB.DEMAND_ID = P.DEMAND_ID
```

The top level subquery exists to get the rows you are interested in and order them in an order which allows predictable results when they are then grouped down by PHASE_ID and DEMAND_ID.  This in turn allows a simple INNER JOIN to DEMAND_STATE hopefully (unless I have misunderstood your query)

This may still be expensive though depending on how much data is within that top level query.

Comment: This query result duplicate row in phase four. Not return only data for four phases. Also i need data from Demand table.